# Android app Tab Switching Crash

Tags: java, android, firebase, tabs

I am currently having an error in my app. I have a recyclerview that loads posts from a firebase database and displays them. When I switch fragments and activities I do not get any errors. When I click the home button or tabs button on my phone and then click back into my app there is a crash with the error message,

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{777f444 position=1
>   id=-1, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{efb45c8 VFED..... .F......
>   0,0-1080,1497 #7f0900c2 app:id/postList},
>   adapter:com.sender.hp.sender.DashboardFragment$2@efd661,
>   layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@9760586,
>   context:com.sender.hp.sender.MainActivity@720f0fa

Whenever I hit the back button on my phone and my app gets closed, If I go into my tabs and hit back into my app it works fine. I don't have an onBackPressed listener.
Here is my code,

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<postsGetInfo, postsGetInfoViewHolder>(postsGetInfo.class, R.layout.posts_layout,postsGetInfoViewHolder.class,postRef) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final postsGetInfoViewHolder viewHolder, postsGetInfo model, int position) {
                    TextView txtUpvote = (TextView) viewHolder.myView.findViewById(R.id.txtUpvoteCount);
                    final String postKey = getRef(position).getKey();
                    viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
                    viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
                    viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                    viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                    viewHolder.setProfileImage(model.getProfileimage());
                    viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage());
                    viewHolder.setDisplayvotes(model.getDisplayvotes());
                    viewHolder.myView.findViewById(R.id.imgDownvote).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                           UpdateTheDisplayVotes(postKey);
                           ++getDownvotes;
                           --getDisplayVotes;
                           String txtDisplayVotes = Integer.toString(getDisplayVotes);
                           postRef.child(postKey).child("downvotes").setValue(getDownvotes);
                           postRef.child(postKey).child("displayvotes").setValue(txtDisplayVotes);
                        }
                    });
                    viewHolder.myView.findViewById(R.id.imgUpvote).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            UpdateTheDisplayVotes(postKey);
                            ++getUpvotes;
                            ++getDisplayVotes;
                            String txtDisplayVotes = Integer.toString(getDisplayVotes);
                            postRef.child(postKey).child("upvotes").setValue(getUpvotes);
                            postRef.child(postKey).child("displayvotes").setValue(txtDisplayVotes);
                        }
                    });

                    viewHolder.myView.findViewById(R.id.imgPost).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent editIntent = new Intent((getActivity()),postEdit.class);
                            editIntent.putExtra("PostKey",postKey);
                            startActivity(editIntent);                                      
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        }

private void UpdateTheDisplayVotes(final String key) {
    VoteListener = postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("displayvotes")){
                displayvotes = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("displayvotes").getValue().toString();
                    getDisplayVotes = Integer.parseInt(displayvotes);
                }
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("upvotes")){
                upvotes = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("upvotes").getValue().toString();
                    getUpvotes = Integer.parseInt(upvotes);
                }
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("downvotes")){
                    downvotes = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("downvotes").getValue().toString();
                    getDownvotes = Integer.parseInt(downvotes);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (firebaseRecyclerAdapter != null){
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.cleanup();
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to fix? Thanks for any answers!

Comment: call `notifyDataSetChanged()` `onStop()` method.

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for the response! If you want to post this as an answer I'll set it as best answer

Comment: Yes. Let me set it as the answer so it can be helpful to others. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when the adapter or list in the adapter is cleared.

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when adapter is cleared.

```
@Override 
public void onStop() { 
    super.onStop(); 
    if (firebaseRecyclerAdapter != null){ 
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.cleanup(); 
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } 
}
```